# Adding a colorbutton in tinymce dialog with api 4.x doesn't work

Tags: dialog, tinymce, color-picker, tinymce-4, window-managers

I'm trying to add a colorbutton in a TinyMCE dialog box to replace my old color selector which was initially created with a select input.

See : [ColorButton : API 4.X](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.ui.ColorButton)

> This class creates a color button control. This is a split button in which the main button has a visual representation of the currently selected color. When clicked the caret button displays a color picker, allowing the user to select a new color.

I can add and see the new colorbutton in the dialog box but it doesn't show the colorpicker when clicked.

[image: ColorButton screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
editor.windowManager.open( {
    title: 'Choose color',
    body: [
        {
            type: 'listbox',
            name: 'bg-color',
            label: 'Color (select)',
            'values': [
                {text: 'White', value: '#FFF'},
                {text: 'Black', value: '#000'},
                {text: 'Silver', value: 'silver'},
            ]
        },
        {
            type: 'ColorButton',
            name: 'bg-color2',
            label: 'Color (colorpicker)',
        },
    ],
    onsubmit: function(e) {
        // Do something here
    }
});
```

And you will find a tinymce fiddle here to illustrate this issue:http://fiddle.tinymce.com/sfeaab

Since my debugger doesn't show any JS error, is there something wrong in this code or is there another way to add a colorpicker in a dialogbox?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 can you create a tinymce.fiddle? (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/)?

Comment: +1 for the question. I am having the same issue as MavBzh

Comment: Here is a tinymce fiddle to illustrate this issue: [http://fiddle.tinymce.com/sfeaab](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/sfeaab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MavBzh I think you've a wrong perception on how the color button works. The ColorButton UI is only help with rendering a button which not much difference with PanelButton UI. you can see this example http://fiddle.tinymce.com/sfeaab/3 in this fiddle I use **textcolor** plugin example.

So, in order to use color button you're required to specify the Panel to hold the color picker.

```
{
    type: 'colorbutton',
    name: 'color',
    text: 'Color',
    selectcmd: 'ForeColor',
    panel: {
        role: 'application',
        ariaRemember: true,
        html: renderColorPicker,
        onclick: onPanelClick
    },
    onclick: onButtonClick

}
```

then later set onclick callback action and render the color picker HTML output yourself, the `renderColorPicker` function is used as the panel content, then assigned onPanelClick callback to put the color to the text placeholder in the ColorButton.

PS: in the fiddle I used v4.0.21

Comment: +1 this works great. but do you know how to insert the selected color value in the editor? I am trying like this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2SU4Tcsd  but it isn't working. Thanks

Comment: Hi and many thanks for this answer! You're right, I had a wrong perception on how it worked. Thanks for the fiddle. Is it possible to change the display of the chosen color on the split button?

Comment: @Towfiq you need to add this line `buttonCtrl._value = value;` in the onPanelClick function so the parent can have the color value.

Comment: @MavBzh it's not possible to change the display for the button unless you modify the tinyMCE ColorButton UI script, it's already predefined by the tinyMCE ColorButton UI. If you try to make a colorpicker, I would suggest you create your own callback, I've tried this in WordPress tinymce by modifying the callback of the windows using TextBox UI.

Comment: here is my fiddle but will only works in WordPress, if you're also working on WordPress tinyMCE make sure you enqueue all the required color picker script http://fiddle.tinymce.com/lheaab/1

Comment: Nackle the code you provided didn't work but, I got into the right direction. thanks

Comment: @Towfiq would suggest you to use `console.log( this )` to debug the object in firebug :)

Comment: @nackle your buttonCtrl._value = value; doesn't work for me. Could you assist? Here is my fiddle:http://fiddle.tinymce.com/FYeaab It works for the older version of mce but I need it to work for the latest.

Comment: @nackle Could you assist with my above comment? I'm really stuck on this :(

Comment: @nackle here is a new fiddle with a working dropdown, http://fiddle.tinymce.com/sZeaab i still need help getting the variable to pass through on submit though

Comment: @ZacNespral21, Hi sorry for late reply, been on hiatus due to accident. Do you still need help with tinyMCE? also if it's about WordPress tinyMCE please post the question to wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ZacNespral21, if you're still need the colorpicker for tinyMCE and WordPress, I made a small tutorial here http://wp.me/p5xRVo-2y

Comment: I wonder why you created the function "renderColorPicker". Is there a way to popup the existing colorpicker of tinymce?

Comment: @Jonny renderColorPicker is needed since the tinyMCE do not have a built in colorpicker, the function will handle the color button to display it in grid (see the fiddle). It maybe possible to build or call other colorpicker library here but I haven't tested it yet. Also this is an old thread maybe there is a new work around for this issue

Comment: @nonsensecreativity: Tnx, got that in between. There is a ui type for colorpicker you can use to create one and yes, colorpicker plugin therefore required.